# HTTP Error 405 from a Tooltip loading another page

Tags: ajax, iis-7, .net-3.5, prototypejs, prototip

I have a web page that uses tooltips.  I am using [Prototip](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2/) specifically.  One of the options is to use Ajax to load another page within the tool.  The Ajax functionality is coming from the Prototype framework, http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request/.

All I really want to load is an image.  I just don't want the image to load on page creation because there are so many images.  So when I put a link to a .jpg file or even a .html file I receive the error HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed from IIS.  I am running IIS7. Is this an issue with my code or an issue with IIS7?    Also, the other version of the error I am getting is `The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/Images/Items/tech_over_RST.jpg' is not allowed.` I receive this version of the error message when I run in debug mode from VS2010.  I am also using URL Routing but not MVC.

Comment: `POST`-ing to an image file doesn't make any sense... you should be using `GET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to see the code you're using. However, "405.0 Method Not Allowed" error when you **POST** some information to an image file makes perfect sense: you can post data to scripts such as ASP, ASPX, PHP or CGI scripts but not to images/documents such as JPG, GIF, HTML etc. And you should not specify an image file as the URL for an AJAX GET/POST request in the first place.

Comment: That works.  I really had a point of confusion there and the whole post vs get straightened me out.